# Error: EACCES, unlink...

Tags: shell, meteor, terminal

I'm trying to get my meteor app up and running, but I don't understand the error that its throwing at all, which is:

```
/Users/ten3/.meteor/packages/meteor- tool/.1.1.10.1b51q9m++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:278
                    throw(ex);
                          ^
Error: EACCES, unlink '/Users/ten3/Desktop/git/ten/website/prospect-recovery/prospect-recovery/.meteor/local/db/mongod.lock'
at Object.Future.wait (/Users/ten3/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1b51q9m++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:398:15)
at /tools/fs/files.js:1331:28
at Object.wrapper [as unlink] (/tools/fs/files.js:1334:20)
at findMongoAndKillItDead (/tools/runners/run-mongo.js:318:11)
at launchOneMongoAndWaitForReadyForInitiate (/tools/runners/run-mongo.js:400:7)
at launchMongo (/tools/runners/run-mongo.js:656:7)
at [object Object]._.extend._startOrRestart (/tools/runners/run-mongo.js:756:19)
at [object Object]._.extend.start (/tools/runners/run-mongo.js:714:10)
at /tools/runners/run-all.js:168:26
- - - - -
```

I'm running a shell script before I try to run a local copy of my meteor app. It supposed to stop my application from interacting with other APIs. When I run the script (I'm on a mac) through my terminal, it returns '0' which as I read means that there are zero errors. I know that the error message is guiding me to certain lines of code, but I don't understand why I would change them if my co-worker could get his copy up and running. He is running his application on a windows computer. Thank you. I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: EACCESS is a permissions error. Here's the first google result, it should point you in the right direction. https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/893

Comment: @thatgibbyguy I'm not getting a 'permission denied' with EACCES though. and even making sure the permission are set correctly, my error remains the same.

Comment: delete `/Users/ten3/Desktop/git/ten/website/prospect-recovery/prospect-recovery/.meteor/local/db/mongod.lock` manually, then start your app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a permission error just as @thatgibbyguy first suggested. I was able to run it buy using `sudo meteor` to override the permission restrictions. I wasn't about to remove my `mongod.lock` file since that my coworker had the file and was able to get it up and running.

Comment: I opened an old project that could've been created me logged in as sudo su.  So, got the same error. Followed Bart's advice and simply ran sudo meteor, and it compiled. Thanks.